# Java InputStream to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, inputstream, bytebuffer

I am reading dds textures, but since once built the jar I can't access those textures through `url` and `file` and have to use `InputStream` instead.

So I would need to know how I can obtain a `java.​nio.ByteBuffer` from an `java.io.InputStream`.

**Ps:** no matter through 3rd part libraries, I just need it working

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For me the best in this case is [Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to handle this and similar tasks.

The `IOUtils` type has a static method to read an `InputStream` and return a `byte[]`.

```
InputStream is;
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Internally this creates a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and copies the bytes to the output, then calls `toByteArray()`.

**UPDATE**: as long as you have the `byte array`, as [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) pointed, you have to convert to `ByteBuffer`

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
```

---

**JAVA 9 UPDATE**: as stated by [@saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279/saka1029) if you're using java 9+ you can use the default `InputStream` API which now includes [`InputStream::readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) function, so no external libraries needed

```
InputStream is;
byte[] bytes = is.readAllBytes()
```

Comment: and then to ByteBuffer?

Comment: @elect yes, `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)`

Comment: it may OutOfMemory

Comment: @chen it may OOM. This method is for small files only. That's why people invented InputStream API :-) >> to read something as a stream (some piece after piece).

Answer (score 5):

What is about:

```
ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);

while (channel.read(buffer) != -1) {
  //write buffer

};
```

Comment: Are you sure that `read()` returns -1 when input stream ends? Sometimes it returns 0.

Comment: Yes, I am %)) this is from javadoc from ReadableByteChannel


```Returns:
The number of bytes read, possibly zero, or -1 if the channel has reached end-of-stream```

Comment: If the buffer isn't big enough to read the entire input stream this can get stuck in a busy loop trying to read 0 bytes over and over.  Depending on how the body of the loop deals with the buffer. e.g. if you just want to read everything into a buffer and return the buffer, so the buffer won't be emptied or flipped in the loop.

Comment: @happy_marmoset It returns -1 at end of stream, and 0 if the buffer is full or if you are reading from a non-ready non-blocking `SocketChannel`.

Comment: @swpalmer That's what `compact()` is for.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, I know.  I was just pointing out that there are assumptions about the body of the loop. E.g. where did the "write buffer" idea come from? The OP is reading "dds textures" (whatever they are) and presumably needs the entire contents of the stream in memory at once. `compact()` likely doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

A neat solution with no 3rd party library needed is

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(inputStream.available());
Channels.newChannel(inputStream).read(byteBuffer);
```

See [ReadableByteChannel#read(ByteBuffer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer))

Comment: Are you sure that one `read()` is enough to read all input stream?

Comment: No, it depends on the `InputStream` you are using. If it has all the bytes available then it will work.

Comment: This is not a correct use of `InputStream.available()`, and the Javadoc specifically says so. It does not return the total number of bytes in the stream, and may return zero.

Answer (score 1):

From Java 9, there is method [readAllBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) (in class `java.io.InputStream`) that returns a byte array. You pass that byte array to [static] method [wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap(byte%5B%5D)) (in class `java.nio.ByteBuffer`), for example:

```
public ByteBuffer fromInputStrem(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(is.readAllBytes());
}
```