# How to create MappedByteBuffer from the ByteArrayInputStream?

Tags: java, bytearrayinputstream, mappedbytebuffer

I have an API which returns me the content in form of ByteArrayInputStream basically which is a video content. Now for streaming it looks MappedByteBuffer seems best fit. So how to convert this ByteArrayInputStream to an instance of MappedByteBuffer?

Comment: `MappedByteBuffer` is used to map a file region into memory. `ByteArrayInputStream` already keeps a buffer in memory. Why would you want to transform one into another? Also consider this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026060/java-inputstream-to-bytebuffer.

Comment: Well sometimes the Bytearrayinputstream is a very big value. And I am getting an out of memory exception. @yegodm